# Difference when serializing a lazy val with or without @transient

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark, lazy-initialization, transient

Working on spark, sometimes I need to send a non-serializable object in each task.

A common pattern is `@transient lazy val`, e.g

```
class A(val a: Int)

def compute(rdd: RDD[Int]) = {
  // lazy val instance = {
  @transient lazy val instance = {
    println("in lazy object")
    new A(1)
  }
  val res = rdd.map(instance.a + _).count()
  println(res)
}

compute(sc.makeRDD(1 to 100, 8))
```

I found that `@transient` is not necessary here. `lazy val` can already create the non-serializable upon each task is executed. But people suggest using `@transient`.

1. What is the advantage, if we set `@transient` on the non-initialized `lazy val` when serializing it ?
2. Does it make sense to make a non-initialized `val` transient for serialization, knowing that nothing will be serialized, just like in the example above ?
3. How is a `@transient lazy val` serialized ? Is it treated as a method or something else ?

Some details on serializing `@transient lazy val` and the compiled java bytecode is awesome.

Answer (score 19):

see here - http://fdahms.com/2015/10/14/scala-and-the-transient-lazy-val-pattern/

In Scala lazy val denotes a field that will only be calculated once it is accessed for the first time and is then stored for future reference. With @transient on the other hand one can denote a field that shall not be serialized.

Comment: is the difference between `@transient lazy val` and `def` that the former will be calculated once per deserialization when first called and the latter will be calculated every time it's called?

Answer (score 0):

`lazy val` works because you don't use it in the driver process so the field remains null and serialization works. If you do use it in the driver process then `@transient` is required.