# spark kryo register generic classes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, kryo

```
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.rtree2d.core._
import EuclideanPlane._

val box1 = entry(1.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, "Box 1")
val box2 = entry(2.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, "Box 2")
val entries = Seq(box1, box2)

val rtree = RTree(entries)
val broadcastedIndex = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(rtree)
```

fails when forcing kryo serialization, i.e. when starting spark with a configuration of:

```
.set("spark.serializer", classOf[KryoSerializer].getCanonicalName)
.set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")
```

As the `RTreeNode` class is not registered. So far, so good.

The problem arises when trying to:
- use `KryoSerializer` but not force kryo: spark gets stuck / does not continue operation
- trying to register the classes:

```
Class is not registered: com.github.plokhotnyuk.rtree2d.core.RTree
```

can be fixed with:

```
kryo.register(Class.forName("com.github.plokhotnyuk.rtree2d.core.RTreeNode"))
```

However, `Class is not registered: com.github.plokhotnyuk.rtree2d.core.RTree[]`

```
kryo.register(classOf[scala.Array[com.github.plokhotnyuk.rtree2d.core.RTreeNode[A]]])
```

fails to compile as I cannot register a **generic** `RTreeNode` to spark when trying to create a custom kryo registrator within the `com.github.plokhotnyuk.rtree2d.core` namespace to access the private classes.

How can I get generic classes registered without specifying a concrete implementation or alternatively prevent spark from getting stuck when falling back to java serialization?

> NOTE when not using kryo at all it works just fine.

### edit

[Spark Kryo register for array class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106392/spark-kryo-register-for-array-class)

```
kryo.register(Array.newInstance(Class.forName("com.github.plokhotnyuk.rtree2d.core.RTreeNode"), 0).getClass())
```

in java, unfortunately, I fail to get this to compile in scala.

Answer (score 0):

Please try combination of lazy and transient.

```
Scala lazy val denotes a field that will only be calculated once it is accessed for the first time and is then stored for future reference.

With @transient on the other hand one can denote a field that shall not be serialized.

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769220/difference-when-serializing-a-lazy-val-with-or-without-transient
```

Comment: No this is not going to work. For a broadcast variable I do need to also serialize its contents.

Comment: In that case you might have to write a custom serializer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144618/spark-kryo-register-a-custom-serializer